# ImageMagick Java API

Tags: java, imagemagick

Is there any ImageMagick Java API ?

-Ken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org/). It uses JNI.

By saying that **it uses JNI**, I am saying that it's not a pure 100% **Java API**. you still need ImageMagick's native (platform dependent) libraries.

There is also the possibility of using ImageMagick's command line utilities to interface it with a Java application. It's my preferred choice when using ImageMagick from a Java Web Application (you don't need any special Java API for that).

Answer (score 4):

There's also [im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/) which uses the command-line approach. I'm using it in a project both on OSX and Linux (just for rescaling) - works like a charm.

Comment: im4java is a pain to use